# PyCharm: JavaScript files under src directory locked

Tags: javascript, django, pycharm

I'm working on a Django 1.4.x project in PyCharm 3.0 on OS X Mountain Lion.  My project is in its own virtualenv.

For some reason, I can't edit any JavaScript files in any Django app found in the src directory (under External Libraries in the project browser).  It doesn't seem to matter what the permissions are or whether the file was created by PyCharm or something else.  Other editors are able to make changes to the files without issue

I've tried locking/unlocking the file in the lower right corner.  Also, the JS icon on the tab at the top does have a lock on it, but I can't interact with it.

My coworker has the same problem.

I've been using PyCharm for 2 years but only recently updated from 2.x to 3.

Apps in my src directory:

```
beanstalkd
coffin
django-account
django-amc-ldap
django-cache-machine
django-cachecow
django-categories
django-chosen
django-ckeditor
django-contact-form
django-cropduster
django-curated
django-dart
django-fatpages
django-forms-builder
django-gcm
django-google-auth
django-grappelli
django-haystack
django-ios-notifications
django-locking
django-omniture
django-partner-feeds
django-push-notifications
django-sentry
django-taggit
django-twitter-feed-cache
ge-admin-login-captcha
ge-contact
ge-content-utils
ge-events
ge-feeds
ge-gbc
ge-migration
ge-newsletters
ge-newsml
ge-organizations
ge-tsp-ticker
genericadmin
pip-delete-this-directory.txt
pybeanstalk
redis
revision
south
```

Comment: Give us a tree print of your libraries.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You just want the names of the libraries under src?  How far down do you want me to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated to PyCharm 3.0.2, and it works now.  Somewhere in the last two patches this was resolved.

(Note: we had tried to patch before, but the automated updated didn't actually patch it for some reason.  I had to download the new version from the website and **reinstall**.)